# DataGrid for WPF and Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, datagrid

Is there a DataGrid component that behaves the same in WPF and Silverlight? There are some small differences in DataGrids from MS (WPF and Silverlight Toolkits). For example, while WPF version has `CanUserAddRows` property, Silverlight version does not.

Comment: That is why you use a pattern like MVVM - to abstract out and isolate differences like that :)

Comment: Of course I do use MVVM, but I want to have my .xaml fo SL and WPF as similar as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up - there nothing like that so I have to care about differences in the code by myself.

**Edit:** Most of the differences can be handled by styles - simply create one DataGrid style for WPF and one for Silverlight.